# How to use Docverter in AngularJS/NodeJS to convert GENERATED html to pdf for downloading

Tags: angularjs, node.js, pdf, docverter

API of [docverter](http://www.docverter.com/) is mentioned in curl format as shown below

```
curl \
  http://c.docverter.com/convert \
  -F from=html \
  -F to=pdf \
  -F input_files[]=@<(echo hello)
```

API states that `input_files[]` value should be a `multipart/form-data file` upload but in my AngularJS application, I am dynamically generating a report (at a specific route) which means it is not an html file which can be uploaded using file upload control.

My question may be bit vague because by looking at the [docverter API](http://www.docverter.com/api), I am not able to know what code goes on client and what goes on server.

Overall I am looking for a solution which converts the generated HTML (along with stylesheet) to PDF file and this PDF file is then downloaded to the browser.

On the server side, I am using Node.js. Appreciate if you can provide clarity on how this conversion happens.

Comment: No. Eventually I dropped it and used phantomjs on server side to convert html to pdf. Let me know if you want to know this.

Comment: I'm on a mission to get this one handled... and with no go-between server.  I'm avoiding the phantomjs method because it's heavy server side and only solves pdf's I need docx and rtf as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok here is the server side fix to get the cors issues worked out with docverter.

It's actually very little code to get it up and running.

These changes happen in `lib/docverter-server/app.rb`

```
class DocverterServer::App < Sinatra::Base

# added code starts here ==>

before do
  headers 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' => '*', 
          'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' => ['OPTIONS', 'GET', 'POST'] ,
          'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' => 'Content-Type',
          'Content-Disposition'  => 'attachment',
          'Content-Type' => 'application/octet-stream'
end

# <=== added ends starts here

set :show_exceptions, false
```

To fix errors so they don't just show cors conflicts

`[500, {'Content-Type' => 'application/json', 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' => '*'}, [MultiJson.dump(hash)]]`

in `lib/docverter-server/error-handler.rb`

As for the angular client side => I document that fix with my own stack question here:

[uploading text blob as file using $http or $resource with angular.js - mimicking curl style multipart/form upload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36855944/uploading-text-blob-as-file-using-http-or-resource-with-angular-js-mimicking?lq=1)

Comment: Thanks for your wonderful efforts. As of now, I am going to stick with phantomjs but would definitely try out your solution in the linked question. I'll be needing docx conversion in the near future. Thanks a lot, I'm marking it as accepted answer as it has given me direction, lots of useful concepts about FormData and Blob and solution.